# Are the quaternions obsolete in pure mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, number-systems

I remember I read an article saying that "The quaternions $\Bbb{H}$ are obsolete in pure mathematics since the theory of vectors has been developed enough, however it is useful in computer science".

Is this true?

I want to know the reason in detail.. How specifically does the theory on vectors affect quaternions?

Moreover, I don't get the point of that article. If quaternions are only for describing 3D motions, then what's the point of expanding it to octonion and other stuffs?

Comment: That's ridiculously false. Quaternion algebras are an active area in the study of elliptic curves and modular forms. You are completely right that $3D$ motions are barely the beginning of the applications of quaternions.

Comment: @AdamHughes Thank you! but would you please tell me how quaternions are useful in elliptic curves?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_algebra#Application has a cursory list of topics, it's too long to just describe them all if you don't know what Brauer groups are (or--if you do--you won't need me to explain the use).

Comment: Here's something else that's more satisfying:  http://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2009/05/14/endomorphisms-of-elliptic-curves-and-the-tate-module/

Comment: These notes of John Baez on Exceptional Lie Algebras reference the Quaternions and particularly the Octonions: http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in the late 19th century, there was fierce competition between quaternions and vectors.  See e.g.
[this talk by Michael J. Crowe](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~temple/MAT21D/SUPPLEMENTARY-ARTICLES/Crowe_History-of-Vectors.pdf).  By 1910 or so, what we now call Vector Analysis had won the day, so e.g. nobody formulates Maxwell's equations using quaternions any more.  But that's more "applied mathematics" than "pure".
In terms of abstract algebra, the quaternions are still an important example, although perhaps not as important as some of the early quaternion enthusiasts
believed.